# What proc values do the witch doctors skills have?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

What are the proc values (effect probability, e.g. for crowd control damage) for the different skills of the witch doctor?

Some are given in the Patch 1.0.4 notes:

- Firebomb - Fire Pit: 0.067
- Gargantuan: 0
- Spirit Barrage - Manitou: 0.125
- Zombie Dogs

  - Rabid Dogs: 0.1
  - Burning Dogs: 0.05

For theory crafting, I'd love a full list. If you answer, please link your sources if available!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Witch Doctor Skill Coefficients**

> One use of proc coefficients is determining how much life on hit is
>   received for every skill you use. If you have 100 life on hit and a
>   skill you are using has a 150% return value, you will receive 150 life
>   each time you use the skill on a enemy.
>
> Proc coefficients also modify the chance of chance on hit abilities.

**Primary Skills**

```
+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
|   Poison Darts    | Return Value | Corpse Spiders  | Return Value |
+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
| No Rune           | 200%         | No Rune         | 8%           |
| Splinters         | 33%          | Leaping Spiders | 8%           |
| Numbing Dart      | 200%         | Spider Queen    | 30%          |
| Spined Dart       | 200%         | Widowmakers     | 8%           |
| Flaming Dart      | 100%         | Medusa Spiders  | 8%           |
| Snake to the Face | 200%         | Blazing Spiders | 8%           |
+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+

+------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
| Plague of Toads  | Return Value |   Firebomb     | Return Value |
+------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
| No Rune          | 66%          | No Rune        | 66%          |
| Explosive Toads  | 66%          | Flash Fire     | 20%          |
| Toad of Hugeness | 100%         | Roll the Bones | 22%          |
| Rain of Toads    | 50%          | Fire Pit       | 6%           |
| Addling Toads    | 66%          | Pyrogeist      | 16%          |
| Toad Affinity    | 66%          | Ghost Bomb     | 12%          |
+------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
```

**Secondary Skills**

```
+-------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| Grasp of the Dead | Return Value |   Fire Bats   | Return Value |
+-------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| No Rune           | 16%          | No Rune       | 16%          |
| Unbreakable Grasp | 16%          | Dire          | 16%          |
| Groping Eels      | 16%          | Vampire       | 16%          |
| Death is Life     | 16%          | Plague        | 16%          |
| Desperate Grasp   | 16%          | Hungry        | 33%          |
| Rain of Corpses   | 12%          | Cloud of Bats | 25%          |
+-------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+

+-----------+--------------+------------------+--------------+
|   Haunt   | Return Value |   Locust Swarm   | Return Value |
+-----------+--------------+------------------+--------------+
| No Rune   | 100%         | No Rune          | 33%          |
| Consuming | 100%         | Pestilence       | 33%          |
| Resentful | 100%         | Devouring Swarm  | 33%          |
| Lingering | 100%         | Cloud of Insects | 33%          |
| Grasping  | 100%         | Diseased Swarm   | 33%          |
| Draining  | 100%         | Searing Locusts  | 33%          |
+-----------+--------------+------------------+--------------+
```

**Defensive Skills**

```
+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+
| Summon Zombie Dogs | Return Value |      Horrify       | Return Value |
+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+
| No Rune            | -            | No Rune            | -            |
| Rabid Dogs         | 10%          | Phobia             | -            |
| Final Gift         | -            | Stalker            | -            |
| Life Link          | -            | Face of Death      | -            |
| Burning Dogs       | 5%           | Frightening Aspect | -            |
| Leeching Beasts    | -            | Ruthless Terror    | -            |
+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+
+-----------------+--------------+------------------------+--------------+
|   Spirit Walk   | Return Value |          Hex           | Return Value |
+-----------------+--------------+------------------------+--------------+
| No Rune         | -            | No Rune                | -            |
| Jaunt           | -            | Hedge Magic            | -            |
| Honored Guest   | -            | Jinx                   | -            |
| Umbral Shock    | 33%          | Angry Chicken          | -            |
| Severance       | 20%          | Painful Transformation | -            |
| Healing Journey | -            | Unstable Form          | -            |
+-----------------+--------------+------------------------+--------------+
```

**Terror**

```
+-------------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+
|   Soul Harvest    | Return Value |    Sacrifice     | Return Value |
+-------------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+
| No Rune           | -            | No Rune          | 100%         |
| Swallow your Soul | -            | Back Blood       | 16%          |
| Siphon            | -            | Next of Kin      | 16%          |
| Languish          | -            | Pride            | 16%          |
| Soul to Waste     | -            | For the Master   | 16%          |
| Vengeful spirit   | 25%          | Provoke the Pack | 16%          |
+-------------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+
+-------------------+--------------+
|  Mass Confusion   | Return Value |
+-------------------+--------------+
| No Rune           | -            |
| Unstable Realm    | -            |
| Devolution        | -            |
| Mass Hysteria     | -            |
| Paranoia          | -            |
| Mass Hallcination | 13%          |
+-------------------+--------------+
```

**Decay**

```
+-----------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------+
| Zombie Charger  | Return Value |    Spirit Barrage     | Return Value |
+-----------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------+
| No Rune         | 50%          | No Rune               | 100%         |
| Leperous Zombie | 50%          | The spirit is Willing | 100%         |
| Undeath         | 50%          | Well of Souls         | 33%          |
| Wave of Zombies | 8%           | Phantasm              | 25%          |
| Explosive beast | 50%          | Phlebotomize          | 100%         |
| Zombie Bears    | 11%          | Manitou               | 12%          |
+-----------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------+
+---------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+
|  Acid Cloud   | Return Value | Wall of Zombie   | Return Value |
+---------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+
| No Rune       | 116%         | No Rune          | 16%          |
| Acid Rain     | 280%         | Barricade        | 20%          |
| Lob Blob Bomb | 116%         | Unrelenting Grip | 16%          |
| Slow Burn     | 116%         | Creepers         | 16%          |
| Kiss of Death | 116%         | Pile On          | 50%          |
| Corpse Bomb   | 33%          | Dead Rush        | 16%          |
+---------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+
```

**Voodoo**

```
+---------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
|     Gargantuan      | Return Value | Big Bad Voodoo  | Return Value |
+---------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
| No Rune             | -            | No Rune         | -            |
| Humongoid           | -            | Jungle Drums    | -            |
| Restless Giant      | -            | Rain Dance      | -            |
| Wraithful Protector | -            | Slam Dance      | -            |
| Big Stinker         | -            | Ghost Trance    | -            |
| Bruiser             | -            | Boogie Man      | -            |
+---------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
+-------------------+--------------+
|    Fetish Army    | Return Value |
+-------------------+--------------+
| No Rune           | -            |
| Fetish Ambush     | 10%          |
| Devoted Following | -            |
| Legion of Daggers | -            |
| Tiki Torchers     | -            |
| Head Hunters      | -            |
+-------------------+--------------+
```

Source: [Witch Doctor Skill Proc Coefficients](http://www.diablohub.com/guides/witch-doctor-skill-proc-coefficients/)